# data.color opacity change using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to reduce the opacity for section `<div class="col-md-8">` in the following code:

```
$('.out-of-order-rooms').append('
    <div class="col-md-2" style="padding:1px">
        <div class="well room- well' + ooc + '" style="background-color:' + data.Color + ';color:' + data.FontColor + '; text-align:center;font-size:12px;"> ' + '
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding:1.15em 0.2em 1.15em 0.5em;border-right: 2px solid #eeeeee6e;font-size: 1.6em;">' + data.RoomName + '<input type="hidden" value="' + data.RoomId + '" id="room-id" /></h4>
        </div>' + '
            <div class="col-md-8" style="display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;height: 5.5em;background-color: #8880;text-align: left;padding-left: 0.8em;">
                <h4 style="font-size:1.4em;">' + data.RoomStatusName + '
                    <input type="hidden" class="font"value="' + data.RoomStatusId + '" id="room-id"/>
                </h4>
            </div>' + ' 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>'
```

);

Comment: You may want to share more of your code as it helps others contextualize, including what have you tried but did not work. Also, sometimes it helps to include a working snippet. You can use code playground such as [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), for instance, and then insert a link to it in your question.

Comment: You should be able to do it using the jQuery [css()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp) or the [fadeTo()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp) Methods.

Comment: I added the fadeTo() method in there. but that wasn't the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment above, you should be able to change the opacity of that element using either of the methods [fadeTo()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp) or [css()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp), although the later would be more approprate unless you need to change the opacity over time.

The css() method should be pretty straightforward:

```js
$(".out-of-order-rooms").append('<div class="col-md-8" style="align-items: center;justify-content: center;background-color: #8880;text-align: left;">LESS OPAQUE</div>');

$(".col-md-8").css('opacity', '0.2');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="out-of-order-rooms">OPAQUE</div>
</body>
```

The fadeTo() function would look something along these lines (if you just wanted it to be half opaque right away, which doesn't make much sense):

```js
$(".out-of-order-rooms").append('<div class="col-md-8" style="align-items: center;justify-content: center;background-color: #8880;text-align: left;">LESS OPAQUE</div>');

$(".col-md-8").fadeTo(0, 0.5);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="out-of-order-rooms">OPAQUE</div>
</body>
```

Or, if you wanted it to fade to half opacity over 2500 miliseconds:

```js
$(".out-of-order-rooms").append('<div class="col-md-8" style="align-items: center;justify-content: center;background-color: #8880;text-align: left;">LESS OPAQUE</div>');

$(".col-md-8").fadeTo(2500, 0.5);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="out-of-order-rooms">OPAQUE</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tries with this answer before. But not the solution actually. Thanks!